# [PersistenceUnit: <name>]: unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As stated on the subject, my problem is the `EntityManagerFactory` cannot be built. I am using Maven + Hibernate. I am connecting to a MySQL DB (`<jdbc://mysql://localhost:3306/<dbname>`).

The weird thing here is during debugging in Eclipse, it is working fine. But when I build it using Maven build, the JAR file is throwing such error. I checked the Manifest file already and all the necessary JARs were included in the Class-Path. Below is the error of the JAR displayed in the console:

===========================================================================

```
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 3, 2012 5:01:16 PM class <name>.<name>.<name> <name>
SEVERE: [ERROR]: [PersistenceUnit: <name>] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
[ERROR]: [PersistenceUnit: <name>] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

===========================================================================

## below is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="<name>">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>classname</class>
<properties>
<!-- <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/classifyPE.cfg.xml"/> -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="<value>" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<name>" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

===========================================================================

What am I doing wrong here? Or what am I lacking?
As mentioned, it's working on Debug. But when I package it into JAR,(with all the necessary JARs present in the libs folder), it's not.

Comment: I guess there's more than that in your console right ? Maybe a detailed stack trace?

Comment: There must be more logs below the given execption, please post them

Answer (score 4):

add this in your xml file

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `<class>classname</class>`

I suspect your entity is not named classname, so try specifying the full classpath-name (for example foo.bar.realclassname with realclassname being the name  of your entity-class).

Comment: Are your database-params (aka user, password and so on) hardcoded in persistence.xml or do you use any placeholders? What I means is: are you sure, the same parameters are used?

Answer (score 0):

The `persistence.xml` file is supposed to go in the `META-INF` folder at the root of the jar. Check if it is there or not. I am guessing that this is purely a classpath related issue.

Comment: Yes it is already in the META-INF folder..together with the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your persistence unit. This is important, since the name is used to identify persistence unit related to each EntityManager.

So:

```
<persistence-unit name="<name>">
```

should be replaced with (for instance):

```
<persistence-unit name="myUnit">
```

Comment: Do the same with `<value>` for BD password.

Comment: Those are just dummy units... I did not post the actual name/value but it has already

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dialect is supported with the version of hibernate, particularly if you are using oracle driver.